# What should be the aspect ratio for 32 nm and 45 nm technology?

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I am designing a combinational circuit and the circuit works well.

I want to know if I should directly write a net list rather than generate it through some schematic. What should be the concept behind selecting w/l ratio?

Answer (score 1):

As a designer of a **digital** circuit you generally do not have to worry about the W/L ratio of the transistors.

Actually a schematic and a netlist describe the same thing! They both describe how all components are connected to eachother.

A schematic is easier to read for humans, a netlist is what a computer program expects as input. Fortunately almost every schematic drawing program offers an option to generate a netlist.

For digital circuits the netlist is usually generated from the RTL code which describes what the circuit looks like in terms of gates.

These gates are mostly pre-defined with transistors having a certain W/L and a layout of these transistors and their connections.

So if you designed a digital circuit consisting of gates then you can use ready-made cells for that so you do not have to worry about W/L.

Selecting the W/L ratios of the transistors in these cells is usually trivial, Length is set to the minimum so 32 or 45 nm.

The Width for the NMOS is set to a workable minimum like 200 nm, that depends on the process. As PMOS transistors are intrinsically weaker they need a wider Width compared to the NMOS. Usually 2x wider is a good start so 400 nm for example.

You could also make a much slower/low power version by increasing the value of L. But that increases the size of the transistors!

If you want a gate with a more powerful output, capable of driving many inputs, you would keep L at the minimum but increase W.

Comment: Your answer has too many **pitfalls** for a new student. Even though W/L ratio is usually not a concern for digital designers, choosing W and L is **not a trivial task**. The best pMOS and nMOS width ratio heavily depends on the fabrication process and the desired outcome (i.e., what metric are you trying to enhance?). Moreover, minimum channel length does not always yield "slower" cells, as some technologies can benefit from RSCE. Last but not least, standard cell libraries are only available because someone designed them, so digital designers must also know how to create them.

Comment: *so digital designers must also know how to create them* I strongly disagree and in the real world you will find that what you say is wrong. You should ask some digital designers if they can create a standard library. My bet is that few can. Next time you get the chance, **ask** what people make those standard libraries. Large companies usually have a special department for that. Digital designers concentrate on describing functionality and transferring that into gates. Does everyone who uses a chip be able to design it as well ? Nope.

Comment: it seems your reply is diverging from the original purpose. This question concerns **digital cell design** and not HDL description. Therefore, that's where my statement stands. I am not here to discuss personal opinion or experiences but to point relevant technical details about the question. If you feel my arguments are not coherent, I could point you to some studies that demonstrate the complexity of such question. Also, it goes without saying that it is not expected from students to design optimum cells but to understand the challenges behind the design process.